# Net use returns “System error 67 has occurred” when specify username/password

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, samba

I tried first to connect the remote samba shared folder (Linux) using explorer on a server(Windows server 2012r2)  and entered remote username and password. It works and I can see the remote files.

Then I tried to write a script in powershell.

```
$dest = '\\remote\shared'
$username = '.\username'
$password = 'password'
net use "$dest" $password /USER:$username
```

However it always gives the error of

```
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

But `net use $dest` doesn't give any error. `net use $dest /delete` doesn't return any error either.

Comment: It works for me.  Does the share name that you are actually using have a $ in it?

Comment: No it doesn't have a $. And it works if I remove the user name and password.

Comment: Did you try `remote\username` instead of `.\username`? Does the user exist on the remote system?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `remote\username` works. However, I entered `.\username` when trying in file explorer and it works.

Comment: So apparently Explorer does some funky things that don't work elsewhere. Don't rely on that. Use the correct credentials.

Comment: this is an exact copy of [Net use returns “System error 67 has occurred” when specify username/password](https://superuser.com/q/1131410/241386)